# Express returning 200 even if error from server

Tags: node.js, express, node-fetch

I am trying to connect to a third party endpoint from my express app. With specific body Doing the same request in curl directly to that endpoint gives me a 400 status with a specific error message.

Now using express + node-fetch, I am getting the error message, but I get 200 status code.

```
export async function authenticate() {
  const result =  await fetch(`${config.host}/token`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        key: "someValueThatShouldReturnError"
    })
  });
  console.log(result.status); // this prints 400
  const json = await result.json();
  return json;
}
```

And in the router I have

```
router.post('/auth', handleErrorAsync(async(req: any, resp: Response, err: any) => {
  let res = await authenticate();
  resp.send(res);
}));
```

a temporary solution is to add this in the async function after declaring `json` variable..But I feel this should be handled out of the box.

```
  if (result.status !== 200) {
    throw createError(result.status, json.error);
  }
```

Comment: `resp.status(res.status).send(res)` [reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status)

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `  const json = await result.json();
`

Comment: @MAS to convert the response from server to JSON. Without it I get a response `{
    "size": 0,
    "timeout": 0
}`

Comment: try this, `const status = result.status; const json = await result.json();` then return both values; `return {status , json}`, `const { json, status } = await authenticate();`

Comment: @MAS yes this works, but shouldnt express handle this automatically? :O

Comment: Express is just a mean to help to communicate through HTTP, it doesn't know the business logic we are handling, error or success, we have to handle that ourselves